# Does anyone know how to import and compile a teal file on client side js?

Tags: smartcontracts, algorand

I've been trying to import & compile teal file on client side.

I was able to do it by using file system module on NodeJS but can't do it on client side.

but I'm not sure how do compile it on client side?

Answer (score 0):

Before you compile your teal file, it's very important that you get teal file.

You can either get it from server as response or make an AJAX request to get it as response from server.

Once you've got the teal file.

You can send it to algorand's daemon running either locally or globally via following endpoint for compilation.

More Info About it can be [found here](https://developer.algorand.org/docs/rest-apis/algod/v2/#post-v2tealcompile)

[image]